# Trouble Understanding Code’s Function from Python Tutorial

Tags: python

I have been following Mosh Hamedani’s [tutorial](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc) on Python and he gave an exercise on how to make a car:
I followed the solution, but I still don't understand the  code’s purpose/function

```
command = ""
started = False
stopped = False
while True:
    command = input("> ").lower()
    if command == "start":
        if started:
            print("IT HAS ALREADY STARTED")
        else:
            started = True
            print("Car started")
    elif command == "stop":
        if not started:
            print("Car has already stopped")
        else:
            started = False
            print("car has stopped")
    elif command == "help":
        print("""
start - starts the engine
stop - stops the engine
quit - quits the application""")
    elif command == "quit":
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry I don't understand")
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? If you don't understand why it does anything at all, you're basically asking us to write a Python tutorial, of which there are thousands out there. If there's a specific line you don't understand, or something doesn't work the way you expected it to, please point to that specifically.

Comment: This is a very straightforward piece of code -- you can practically read it like a story.  Have you run the program?

Comment: maybe try doing the tutorial instead of skipping to the answer at the end

Comment: I suggest running it with a debugger and single step through to get an idea how it behaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is a simple script that allows the user to start and stop a car. If the user enters the "start" command, the car will start. If the user enters the "stop" command, the car will stop. If the user enters the "help" command, a list of commands will be printed. If the user enters the "quit" command, the script will exit.